# Window Scroll function over top not correct

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, window

I am running a window scroll function to try and gauge when the div `#home-cover1` is in view. Then when it is not in view for the code to run the else statement.

If you pull up your console, you will see that the else is never running and despite which div you are in it says `#home-cover1` is in view.

Does anyone see why?

```js
$(function() {
  var section1 = $('#home-cover1');
  if (section1.length) {
   var oTop = section1.offset().top - window.innerHeight;
  }
  $(window).scroll(function() {
   var pTop = $(document).scrollTop();
   if (pTop > oTop) {
    console.log("OVer it");
    $('#proposal-trigger').removeClass('active');
   }
   else {
    console.log("Nope it");
    $('#proposal-trigger').addClass('active');
   }
  });
 });
```

```css
#home-cover1 {
  background: green;
  height: 100vh;
   width: 100%;
}
#red {
  background: red;
  height: 100vh;
   width: 100%;
}
#blue {
  background: blue;
  height: 100vh;
   width: 100%;
}
#proposal-trigger {
 background: #3B3B3B;
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 position: fixed;
 bottom: 0;
 right: 200px;
 opacity: 0;
 transition: ease 0.3s;-webkit-transition: ease 0.3s;
}
#proposal-trigger.active {
 opacity: 1;
 transition: ease 0.3s;-webkit-transition: ease 0.3s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="home-cover1"></section>
<section id="red"></section>
<section id="blue"></section>
<div id="proposal-trigger"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a quick check `var oTop = section1.offset().top - window.innerHeight;` results to a negative number therefore `pTop` is always greater than `oTop`. You have to subtract `section1.offset()` by `window.innerHeight`. You also have to switch `pTop > oTop` to `pTop < oTop`. This checks if `scrollTop` has gone below the section.

```js
$(function() {
  var section1 = $('#home-cover1');
  if (section1.length) {
   var oTop = window.innerHeight - section1.offset().top;
  }
  $(window).scroll(function() {
   var pTop = $(document).scrollTop();
      console.log(pTop);
      console.log(oTop);
   if (pTop < oTop) {
    console.log("OVer it");
    $('#proposal-trigger').removeClass('active');
   }
   else {
    console.log("Nope it");
    $('#proposal-trigger').addClass('active');
   }
  });
 });
```

```css
#home-cover1 {
  background: green;
  height: 100vh;
   width: 100%;
}
#red {
  background: red;
  height: 100vh;
   width: 100%;
}
#blue {
  background: blue;
  height: 100vh;
   width: 100%;
}
#proposal-trigger {
 background: #3B3B3B;
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 position: fixed;
 bottom: 0;
 right: 200px;
 opacity: 0;
 transition: ease 0.3s;-webkit-transition: ease 0.3s;
}
#proposal-trigger.active {
 opacity: 1;
 transition: ease 0.3s;-webkit-transition: ease 0.3s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="home-cover1"></section>
<section id="red"></section>
<section id="blue"></section>
<div id="proposal-trigger"></div>
```

Comment: That seems to be acting weird too.